# Servlet-Filter not executing properly when using responseWrapper

Tags: java, hashmap, wrapper, servlet-filters

I am working with a use case where I am storing a complete response (body + headers) corresponding to some id in a **Synchronized** HashMap of type `Map<String,MyCustomResponse>`  inside the servlet-filter layer.

Below is the code for reference:

```java
public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("inside middleware: incoming request");


        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        //calling next
        filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);

        byte[] reqArr = requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
        byte[] resArr = responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();

        String requestBody = this.getStringValue(reqArr, request.getCharacterEncoding());
        String responseBody = this.getStringValue(resArr, response.getCharacterEncoding());


        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();


        MyCustomResponse resp = new MyCustomResponse();

        resp.setBody(responseBody);
        resp.setStatus(responseWrapper.getStatus());
        resp.setHeaders(getResponseHeaderMap(responseWrapper));



        String id = request.getHeader("customId");

        logger.debug("ID: {}", id);

        if (id != null) {
            k.getResp().put(id, resp); // k is some class object where my customMap (Synchronized HashMap) of type Map<String,MyCustomResponse> is present.
            logger.debug("response in custom map: {} ", k.getResp().get(id));
        }
        

        logger.debug("inside middleware: outgoing response");
    }
```

In some other class there is a method called fetchReponse(), inside that I am sending concurrent HTTP requests and also getting responses from the same custom HashMap. **But the problem is sometimes I get the response back and sometimes I get null**.

I know that call to the method `responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse()` results in writing responseBody to the original response & flushBuffer( headers & status code get written + response get committed). and after this method call only it behaves differently.

Ideally, servlet-filter should be executed completly for a particular request hence I should be getting my customresponse always from customMap.

Comment: have you tried concurrenthashmap?

Comment: yes, i did but same result.